# Correlation of categories

Tags: correlation

I am comparing the Facebook posts of a TV news organization's Facebook Page to the contents of the TV news broadcast. (This is called "agenda setting" in communications research.) I have used a grounded theory approach to code hundreds of Facebook posts and segments of the TV show.

Here is the problem: There are about 1500 Facebook posts with 500 code categories and 51 TV segments with 300 code categories. When I test the correlation, I have been testing the top 20 Facebook post categories against the number of times the same categories appear on the TV show. Some people have suggested that I need to test all of the Facebook categories against all of the TV show categories. Is this true? They are not equal in number. As a compromise I have converted the number of times a code appears in Facebook or on TV to percentage - percentage out of 1500 for Facebook and percentage out of 51 for the TV show. Does this seem reasonable? Is there a better way to do this without comparing the 500 to the 300 codes. I am using Pearson's correlation coefficient.

Comment: Pearson's what? Two Pearsons are famous for their statistical innovations, so *lots* of tests and procedures are named for them.  Do you perhaps mean you are computing Pearson correlation coefficients?

Comment: thanks for the note! Yes, it's Pearson's correlation coefficient. I have two variables, I want to see if they are related, and one

Answer (score 1):

I find your approach interesting in that if you are attempting to measure salience transfer, presumably to establish causality, I do not see where you have a control group. In other words is the rank order of the issues discussed by people who watched the news broadcast different from those who did not?

By way of example suppose a key sports team in your city wins the national championship. Most likely it will be covered on the news and most likely most people will be talking about it the next day. But it is also true that they would probably be talking about it even if somehow the TV news failed to cover it.

Also I am curious why you are using a Pearson correlation coefficient rather than a [Spearman Rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) or [Kendal tau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_tau) which to me would seem more appropriate?